# Is a solution to the Hartree-Fock equations guaranteed to exist? Is it a Slater determinant in any basis?

Tags: atomic-physics, computational-physics, physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

My understanding is that the Hartree-Fock equations can be derived from the variational theorem as follows:

The variational theorem states that for an arbitrary wavefunction $|\psi \rangle$, $\langle \psi | H | \psi \rangle \ge E_0$, where $H$ is a Hamiltonian operator. Take then a specific kind of wavefunction that can be written as a Slater determinant (antisymmetrized Hartree product) of single particle wavefunctions $| \chi \rangle$, where each pair $|\chi_j\rangle, |\chi_k\rangle$ are orthonormal. I will denote this kind of wavefunction $|\Delta \rangle$. If we minimize the variational problem

$$L(|\chi_1\rangle,\ldots) = \langle \Delta |H| \Delta \rangle - \sum_{k,j} \left(\epsilon^k_j \langle \chi_j|\chi_k\rangle - 1\right)$$

with with the electronic Hamiltonian:

$$ H = \sum_{j} T_{j} - \sum_{a,j} \frac{Z_a}{r_{aj}} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j,k} \frac{1}{r_{jk}}$$

(hopefully the notation is clear), we see that the solution is given by a set of functions ${\chi_j}$ that fulfill the condition:

$$F_{\{|\chi_j\rangle\}} ~|\chi_j\rangle = \sum_{k} \epsilon^k_j|\chi_k\rangle$$

where the Fock operator, $F$, depends on the set of functions.

My question is this: **Is there any mathematical or physical guarantee that a set of functions that fulfills this condition always exist?** I think maybe the fact that $H$ is bounded from below is justification enough, but I'm not 100% sure.

An extra question I have regarding this is that, since the Fock operator is invariant to the application of a unitary transformation to the set of $\chi$, and since it is possible to find a unitary transformation relating any two orthogonal bases, it seems to me that any set of $\chi$ you find can be extended into an orthogonal basis and then rotated into any basis you want, which would indicate that for *any orthogonal basis whatsoever* there exists a Slater determinant made from basis elements that fullfills this condition. **Is my understanding correct**?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01609845

Comment: @LewisMiller At the time of writing you can find an open link to the PDF of this paper (not behind a paywall) on [the Caltech page for one of the authors](http://www.math.caltech.edu/simon/simon.html).

Comment: Nice! I will definitely take a look